# Fetch url locally in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, typescript

I am working with simple Angular project. I have JSON file of data

```
[{
"name": "Little Collins",
"area": "Bronx",
"city": "New York",
"coverImage": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576808597967-93bd9aaa6bae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1241&q=80"}]
```

This is the interface i am using

```
export interface IRestaurant{
name: string,
area: string,
city: string,
coverImage: string}
```

But i am not able to load that cover image url. I am getting empty list.

```
<ul *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">
<li>{{restaurant.name}} - {{restaurant.area}} - {{restaurant.city}}</li>
<li>{{restaurant.coverImage}}</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<li>
    <img [src]="restaurant.coverImage" />
</li>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7u6c4u?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept and upvote if this was useful :)

Answer (score 3):

Image file is not directly load in HTML, so you need `<img>` tag to load image as following..

```
<img src="{{restaurant.coverImage}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Image file cannot load directly, so you need  tag :

```
  <ul *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">
        <li>
            <img [src]="restaurant.coverImage" height="300"/>
        </li>
  </ul>
```